# How to access USB flash drive in VirtualBox?

Tags: usb, virtualbox, macbook-pro, usb-storage

I’m using MacBook pro and I have installed VirtualBox for using Windows XP. I can’t access USB flash drive when I connect. The USB flash drive is not showing in the workspace. How I can access a USB flash drive from VirtualBox?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you go into the virtual machine's settings, under Ports, you can enable specific USB devices (or all devices, if you so desire):

[image]